# xmlhttprequest not passing variable from javascript to php

Tags: javascript, php, xmlhttprequest

I am make an interactive map in D3. I stored all data in MySQL database. Since the user is able to select year to see all data, I have to pass the year to server side(php) to query about the data of the specific year.

I do not know specific function in D3.js to help us pass variables to php, so I use XMLHTTP to send information to php.
My javascript:

```
a = "ARGGDP"
var xmlHttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
xmlHttp.open("GET", "database/allcountry.php?a=a", true);
xmlHttp.addEventListener("load", ajaxCallback, false);
xmlHttp.send(null);

function ajaxCallback(event){
    alert( "loaded");
}
```

My php

header("Content-Type: application/json");

```
$a = $_GET['a'];
$username = "root";
```

However, it shows "Undefined index: a". Any idea about what should I do to fix this problem?

Answer (score 1):

You missed a ; at the end of your var "a" and didn't add the var to your url.

```
a = "ARGGDP";
var xmlHttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
xmlHttp.open("GET", "database/allcountry.php?a="+a, true);
xmlHttp.addEventListener("load", ajaxCallback, false);
xmlHttp.send();

function ajaxCallback(event){
    alert( "loaded");
}
```

PHP

```
echo "<pre>";
print_r($_GET);
echo "</pre>";
```

Comment: It only prints <pre>Array
(
) in my php page. Since I want to pass a)(table name) into php, I can use variable a in my query.

Answer (score 1):

You can use following;

```
function sendAjax(data) {
  var xmlhttp;
  if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
    xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
  } else {
    xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
  }
  xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function() {
    if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200) {
      alert("loaded")
    }
  }
  xmlhttp.open("GET","database/allcountry.php?a=" + data,true);
  xmlhttp.send();
}

sendAjax("ARGGDP");
```

In php

```
$a = $_GET['a'];
echo $a;
```

Answer (score 0):

Your ajax request is working, the `undefined index: a` notice means the `$_GET` variable does not have a key '`a`', maybe you are modifying $_GET somewhere in your code?